# Saving html to pdf in chrome

Tags: r, google-chrome, pdf-generation, r-markdown

I am using `rmarkdown` to generate an HTML report. I am on a restricted machine, can't install tex. So, I was trying to generate an HTML document and then convert/print it to a pdf. The example markdown document is:

````
---
title: "trials"
author: "Foo Bar"
date: "15 December 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r cars, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, message=FALSE}

library(dplyr, quietly = TRUE)
library(abind, quietly = TRUE)
virginica <- iris %>% filter(Species == "virginica") %>% head() %>% select(-Species)
setosa <- iris %>% filter(Species == "setosa") %>% head() %>% select(-Species)

diff_mat <- virginica - setosa


diff_mat[diff_mat<0] <- '<font color="green">&dArr; </font>'
diff_mat[diff_mat>0] <- '<font color="red">&uArr; </font>'
diff_mat[diff_mat == 0] <- '<font color="blue">&hArr; </font>'

datArray <- abind::abind(virginica, diff_mat, along=3)

fin_dat <- apply(datArray,1:2, function(x)paste(x[1],x[2], sep = " "))

knitr::kable(fin_dat, format = "html",
      escape = FALSE, table.attr = "border=1",
      caption = "Changes across species")

```
````

I can't knit to word either as the formatting is lost as discussed in [HTML formatted tables in rmarkdown word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156265/html-formatted-tables-in-rmarkdown-word-document). The HTML produced is exactly what I wanted. HTML to word using save as in word works mostly fine with some issues and I can print pdf but it is not as good as directly printed from pdf.
[image]

when I try to save it as pdf in chrome the colour is lost.

[image]

There is no issues in print options 
[image]

Other pages such as this question in our beloved site [Replace NA's using data from Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604626/replace-nas-using-data-from-multiple-columns) prints fine

[image]

Do you have any pointers where I am missing a point or where the issue is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this right after the YAML header:

```
<style>
@media print {

  font[color="green"] {
    color: #00ff00!important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
  }

  font[color="red"] {
    color: #ff0000!important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
  }

}
</style>
```

The problem is that RStudio's default R markdown templates use Bootstrap and their version of `bootstrap.min.css` has:

```
@media print {
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
            box-shadow: none !important;
  }
```

in it. That's a pretty "destructive" media query as the `*`'s cause those settings to be applied to *all* tags and `color: #000 !important;` means *"no color for YOU!"* when you print a document. I grok the sentiment behind that (saving the planet + toner/ink costs) but if you're printing to PDF it makes no sense whatsoever.

Unfortunately, there are no hyper-targeted media queries for printing to PDF, so the generic "print" ones get applied when you print web pages to PDFs and these mindless, catch-all media queries take over.

*The problem for you is that you'll need to be very specific in targeting any other tags to override these settings.* Which means adding your own CSS classes to anything you generate in Rmds or getting cozy with "Inspect Element" until you catch'em all.

**However**, if you're feeling adventurous you can modify the YAML header to be:

```
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: false
```

When you render to HTML it'll create a directory with subdirectories for the various components vs base64-encode them into one big document.

I named my document `forso.Rmd` which means it made a directory called `forso_files` and put subdirs under it.

Open up the main HTML file and scroll down until you see something like:

```
<script src="forso_files/jquery-1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link href="forso_files/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="forso_files/bootstrap-3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="forso_files/bootstrap-3.3.5/shim/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="forso_files/bootstrap-3.3.5/shim/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="forso_files/navigation-1.1/tabsets.js"></script>
```

Change this:

```
<link href="forso_files/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

to:

```
<link href="forso_files/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Edit `bootstrap.css`, remove the `color: #000 !important;` line and add the `-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;` line. SAVE A COPY OF `bootstrap.css` ELSEWHERE as it'll get squashed on future renders (i.e. you'll need to copy it back on every render).

You can't just link to a separate CSS file with a less brain dead print media query since the `color: #000 !important;` impacts all tags thanks to the `*` target and you can't just reset it to `initial` or inherit` because that will just turn them black as well.

Your final (and probably best) option is to make your own R Markdown template (see https://github.com/hrbrmstr/markdowntemplates for more info) and avoid placing over-arching print media queries in it.

Comment: Thanks! This is one of the most in-depth answer I have read in SO.