# RMarkdown: Printing css styles

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I'm creating an Html report from RMarkdown applying some simple css and I'm facing some issues when printing output report. Browser version applies correctly css but printed version doesn't. This would be a reproducible example of RMarkdown code:

````
---
title: "Table"
output:
  html_document:
    css: "test.css"
---

```{r}
library(knitr)
data(iris)
kable(iris)
```
````

And this is the content of my test.css file:

```
     .main-container { 
     max-width: 1600px !important;
 } 
    tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2}
    th {
        background-color: #FF6319;
        color: white;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    tbody {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    hr {
        page-break-after: always;
    }
```

How can I manage to get the same results in browser output than in printing output? I tried even checking backgroung graphics option in Chrome printing menu, but nothing changes.
Thank you.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Is the css applied incorrectly or not at all?

Comment: possibly relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/41611312/1457051

Answer (score -1):

I guess the problem is related to "background-color" and "background-image" properties that are ignored by default on many browsers (when printing).

For chrome you can add the following code to your print css, in firefox and IE you must select "print background" in the print dialog.

```
:root {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
```

You can do it like that in HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />

@media print {
    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #f2f2f2  !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }
    th {
        background-color: #FF6319  !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }
}
```